# Using Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership as a job

Tags: powershell, start-job

I want to get the AD Group Membership as a job. Just using

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $objUser.DistinguishedName
```

nicely returns a list of the AD-groups. However when I try this as a job:

```
$Job = Start-Job {Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $objUser.DistinguishedName}
$Job.Name
Wait-Job -Name $Job.Name
Receive-Job -Name $Job.Name
```

I get an error:

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null
>   or empty. Provide an argument that is not  null or empty, and then try
>   the command again.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ParameterBindingValidationExcep
>   tion
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.Get
>   ADPrincipalGroupMembership
>       + PSComputerName        : localhost
>   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jobs are running in the background and not in the current scope, so The Start-Job doesn't know anything about your variables, unless you tell it about them.

```
$DN = $objUser.DistinguishedName
$Job = Start-Job {Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $args[0]} -ArgumentList $DN
$Job.Name
Wait-Job -Name $Job.Name
Receive-Job -Name $Job.Name
```

**Explanation:**

Add your variables with the `-ArgumentList $var1,$var2` parameter then use the `$args[0]` for the first parameter `$args[1]` to the 2nd and so on.

In your case only one parameter is needed, so use `-ArgumentList $DN` and call it with `$args[0]` inside the `start-job` ScriptBlock

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not only does it work, I understand why it works. Great!